# list comprehension using dictionary entries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

trying to figure out how I might be able to use list comprehension for the following:

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {}
dict ['one'] = {"tag":"A"}
dict ['two'] = {"tag":"B"}
dict ['three'] = {"tag":"C"}
```

and I would like to create a list (let's call it "list") which is populated by each of the "tag" values of each key, i.e.

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

is there an efficient way to do this using list comprehension? i was thinking something like:

```
list = [x for x in dict[x]["tag"]]
```

but obviously this doesn't quite work. any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
d = {'one': {'tag': 'A'},
     'two': {'tag': 'B'},
     'three': {'tag': 'C'}}

tag_values = [d[i][j] for i in d for j in d[i]]

>>> print tag_values
['C', 'B', 'A']
```

You can sort the list afterwards if it matters.

If you have other key/value pairs in the inner dicts, apart from 'tag', you may want to specify the 'tag' keys, like this:

```
tag_value = [d[i]['tag'] for i in d if 'tag' in d[i]]
```

for the same result. If 'tag' is definitely always there, remove the `if 'tag' in  d[i]` part.

As a side note, never a good idea to call a `list` 'list', since it's a reserved word in Python.

Comment: If the inner dicts have another key eg `{'tag': 'B', 'foo': 'bar'}` then `bar` will show in the output which is not right. So this solution is fragile.

Comment: I dont see anything from the OP question that guarantees the inner dict to always have one key (and one key only) and since dicts are mutable anything can happen. And one needs to read that list comp 3 times before knowing whats happening, we know we want 'tag' key but we are still iterating over `a` subdict.

Comment: the edit list comp is simpler, better and faster. +1. Oh for the guarantee of the presence of 'tag' its easier to just say `if 'tag' in a[i]` in the end of the list comp. That way its clear you want the tag key and if its not there, you dont just grab anything you find.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extra step but gets the desired output and avoids using reserved words:

```
d = {}
d['one'] = {"tag":"A"}
d['two'] = {"tag":"B"}
d['three'] = {"tag":"C"}
new_list = []
for k in ('one', 'two', 'three'):
    new_list += [x for x in d[k]["tag"]]

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
[i['tag'] for i in dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
untransformed = {
    'one': {'tag': 'A'},
    'two': {'tag': 'B'},
    'three': {'tag': 'C'},
    'four': 'bad'
}
transformed = [value.get('tag') for key,value in untransformed.items() if isinstance(value, dict) and 'tag' in value]
```

It also sounds like you're trying to get some info out of JSON you might want to look into a tool like https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: `'bad'.get('tag')` isn't going to handle errors as nicely as you intend.

Comment: yeah I originally had an if statement in there but removed it